# How to import selected fields in mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

For example I have a table. With a field Idnumber. And the field has 10 data(ex: 1234, 1235, 1236, etc)
And I have another table, subjects. Is it possible to import the data that is in the table student(field idnumber) and put it on the table subjects(field idnumber)?
So that I won't have to copy and paste the data that is in the source table to the destination table.
I'm talking about phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
INSERT INTO `subjects`(`idnumber`) SELECT `idnumber` FROM `studends`;
```

The INSERT command can use data provided by a simple `SELECT`, so you can "copy" data from one table to another using this kind of syntax.